# How am I supposed to find the area of the shaded quadrilateral?

Tags: contest-math

In the diagram (which is not drawn to scale) the small triangles each have the area shown. Find the area of the shaded quadrilateral.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the photo of the problem.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post a photo but the different areas are 7, 14, 4 and x.

Comment: Could you post a link?

Comment: Fixed it, sorry about that.

Comment: how about using Menelaus's Theorem?

Comment: See: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2006_AMC_10B_Problems/Problem_23

Comment: Thanks guys, got an answer of 4.83.

Answer (score 1):

**A POSSIBLE PATH**

Consider the Figure below and let $x$ be the desired area.

[image]

1. By Menelaus's Theorem on $\triangle BCE$ cut by $AD$ you get
   \begin{equation}\frac{\overline{EP}}{\overline{PB}}\cdot\frac{\overline{BD}}{\overline{DC}}\cdot\frac{\overline{AC}}{\overline{AE}}=1.\tag{*}\label{eq1}\end{equation}
2. Observe that the ratio $\frac{\overline{EP}}{\overline{PB}} = \frac12$. Why?
3. Similarly, you can find $\frac{\overline{BD}}{\overline{DC}}=\frac{18}{7+x}$, and $\frac{\overline{AC}}{\overline{AE}}=\frac{25+x}{21}$.
4. This info in \eqref{eq1} will give the equation in $x$ $$7(7+x) = 3(25+x),$$and the final result $x=\frac{13}2$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It can be deduced that the area $[FED] = 7\cdot 4/14=2$.

Furthermore, examine the ratios below,

$$\frac{[FDC]}{[BDC]}=\frac{9}{18}=\frac{\frac{a}{a+b} \frac{d}{c+d}[ABC]  }{ \frac{b}{a+b}[ABC]}  =\frac ab  \frac{1}{\frac cd +1} \tag{1}$$

$$\frac{[FDB]}{[FCB]}=\frac{6}{21}=\frac{\frac{c}{c+d} \frac{b}{a+b} [ABC]  }{ \frac{d}{c+d} [ABC]}  =\frac cd  \frac{1}{\frac ab +1} \tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2),

$$ \frac cd = \frac 12$$

Then, the area of the quadrilateral is

$$[AFED]= 2+ [AFD] = 2+\frac 12\cdot 9 = \frac {13}{2}$$

Comment: A useful identity, easily proven: ΔFAD / ΔFED = ΔCAB / ΔCEB. Shaded area: (x-2)/2 = (7+14+4+x)/14 → 7x-14 = 25+x → 6x = 39 → x = 13/2

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution obtained by splitting the area to be found into two areas $x$ and $y$ by diagonal $CM$ (see figure).

[image]

This diagonal allows to use the fact that $\dfrac{[ACM]}{[MCA']}=\dfrac{[BAM]}{[MAB']}=\dfrac{AM}{MA'}$ (ratio of areas equal to the ratio of bases because of a common height) :

$$\dfrac{7+x}{y}=\dfrac{14}{4}\left(=\dfrac{AM}{MA'}\right)\tag{1}$$

For a similar reason, $\dfrac{[B'CM]}{[MCB]}=\dfrac{[B'AM]}{[MAB]}=\dfrac{BM}{MB'}$ giving :

$$\dfrac{x}{y+4}=\dfrac{7}{14}\left(=\dfrac{BM}{MB'}\right)\tag{2}$$

(1) and (2) give rise to a linear system of 2 equations in the 2 unknowns $x$ and $y$ ; its solutions are :

> $$x=\dfrac72 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ y=3, $$
>   giving finally total area
>
> $$x+y=\dfrac{13}{2}.$$

Remark : one can find in book 6 of Euclides : "Triangles sharing the same altitude are between themselves [understand : their resp. areas] as their bases."

Comment: No comment on this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build a general formula for the shaded area.
To simplify, **assume base area = 1**.  We can scale it back later.

Let left and right triangle area be $x, y$. Solving for shaded area, $z$
Using @dfnu setup, with symbols instead of actual numbers:
$${EP \over PB}{BD \over DC}{AC \over AE} = {x \over 1}{1+y \over x+z}{1+x+y+z \over 1+x} = 1$$
$$\large z = {x + y + 2 \over {1 \over x\,y} - 1}$$

Note: the formula implied $x\,y < 1$

For this example, $\large x={7\over14}, y={4\over14}$, we have $\large z={13\over28}$

Scaled back with actual base area of 14, we have shaded area = $\large{13\over2}$

Lets get the area of ΔABC (still, assume base area = 1):

$$ΔABC = 1+x+y+z = {(1+x)(1+y) \over 1-x\,y}$$